# Trying to connect to external .net browser hosted in desktop application

Tags: playwright

I am trying to use playwright to interact with an external .net browser hosted inside a desktop application.
I'm able to connect to the application using connectOverCDP but wasn't able to interact with the elements.

```
import { test} from '@playwright/test';

const pw = require("playwright");

test('test', async ({ page }) => {
  const browser = await pw.chromium.connectOverCDP("http://localhost:9222");
  await page.locator('[aria-label="Screencast view of debug target"]').click(); // keeps failing here
});
```

Comment: what is the error in the output ? I think you need to create a Browser Context